# ggplot2 facet_grid custom labeller with group, subscript and value

Tags: r, ggplot2

In summary, my question is how to create labels for `facet_grid` with (1) `group("|",A['i,j'],"|")` *and* (2) `value`?

For (1), using `expression()`, I can only get it to work **without** `value`:

```
plot_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  print(value)
  if (variable=='FOO') {
    expr1 <- expression(group("|",A['i,j'],"|"))
    return(expr1)
  } else {
    return("bla")
  }
}
```

For (2), displaying the `value`, using `paste()` works for rather simple math expr, only. For example:

```
plot_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  if (variable=='FOO') {
    expr1 <- paste("alpha"," : ",value)
    return(expr1)
  } else {
    return("bar")
  }
}
```

However, `paste()` does not work with `group()` (e: could not find function "group"). Even without `group()` it does not work: "A['i,j']" is then displayed "as is", i.e., without applying `plotmath`. Using `bquote()` as in:

```
plot_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  if (variable=='FOO') {
    expr1 <- bquote(group("|",A['i,j'],"|") : .(value))
    return(expr1)
  } else {
    return("bar")
  }
}
```

does not work, either:

```
Error in labels[, i] <- labeller(names(label_df)[i], label_df[, i]) : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Printing the bquoted expression with `text()` works, though.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Paul!  Since the code you mention at the top of your question doesn't work (and thus is an imperfect guide to what you *do* want), perhaps beginning your post with a text description of what you're trying to achieve would make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: As already mentioned hard to help you without a reproducible exmaple. Try to change the returned value to a list. Fo example :   change `return(expr1)` by `lapply(value, function(x) eval(substitute(expr1)))`

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have edited the question, starting with a working example. Unfortunately, using `lapply()` does not work either. It results in labels with `value` as a string, not the actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's a simpler and better way, but here's an idea:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, f=gl(2,5, labels=c("FOO","BLAH")))

make_label <- function(value)
  bquote(group("|",A['i,j'],"|"):.(value))

plot_labeller <- function(variable,value){
  print(value)
  if(variable=='f')
    do.call(expression, lapply(levels(value)[value], make_label)) else "other"
}

qplot(x,y,data=d) + facet_grid(.~f, labeller=plot_labeller)
```