# Add axis tick-marks on top and to the right to a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `base` graphics we can easily add tick-marks at different sides of the plot by using `axis` and the `side` argument:

```
par(tck = 0.025)
plot(1:10)
axis(side = 3, labels = FALSE)
axis(side = 4, labels = FALSE)
```

How can I mirror x and y axis ticks on the top and right in `ggplot2`? There is `annotation_logticks` which can do this, but only seems to work well for logarithmic scales (as the name of the function applies). For linear scales, is there a similarly easy way?

Comment: Easy? Probably [not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15334494/324364).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This mirrors the axis tick marks (using `gtable` functions), and puts the tick marks inside the plot panel.

**EDIT 18 April 2016** `axis.ticks.margin` is deprecated. Use text margins instead.

**EDIT 19 Mrch 2015**: Better positioning of the tick marks

```
library(ggplot2) # v2.1.0
library(gtable)  # v0.2.0
library(grid)

# Get a plot
p = ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10), aes(x,y)) + 
   geom_point() +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.25, "cm"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = .5, unit = "cm")),
          axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = .5, unit = "cm")))

# Convert the plot to a grob
gt <- ggplotGrob(p)

# Get the position of the panel in the layout
panel <-c(subset(gt$layout, name=="panel", se=t:r))

## For the bottom axis
# Get the row number of the bottom axis in the layout
rn <- which(gt$layout$name == "axis-b")

# Extract the axis (tick marks only)
axis.grob <- gt$grobs[[rn]]
axisb <- axis.grob$children[[2]]  # Two children - get the second
axisb  # Note: two grobs - tick marks and text

# Get the tick marks
xaxis = axisb$grobs[[1]]  # NOTE: tick marks first
xaxis$y = xaxis$y - unit(0.25, "cm")  # Position them inside the panel

# Add a new row to gt, and insert the revised xaxis grob into the new row.
gt <- gtable_add_rows(gt, unit(0, "lines"), panel$t-1)
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, xaxis, l = panel$l, t = panel$t, r = panel$r, name = "ticks")

## Repeat for the left axis
# Get the row number of the left axis in the layout
panel <-c(subset(gt$layout, name=="panel", se=t:r))
rn <- which(gt$layout$name == "axis-l")

# Extract the axis (tick marks and axis text)
axis.grob <- gt$grobs[[rn]]
axisl <- axis.grob$children[[2]]  # Two children - get the second
axisl  # Note: two grobs -  text and tick marks

# Get the tick marks
yaxis = axisl$grobs[[2]] # NOTE: tick marks second
yaxis$x = yaxis$x - unit(0.25, "cm") # Position them inside the panel

# Add a new column to gt, and insert the revised yaxis grob into the new column.
gt <- gtable_add_cols(gt, unit(0, "lines"), panel$r)
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, yaxis, t = panel$t, l = panel$r+1, name = "ticks")

# Turn clipping off
gt$layout[gt$layout$name == "ticks", ]$clip = "off"

# Draw it
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: When i try to reproduce this code i got left and bottom ticks half inside half outside of the axes and also i got warning: Warning message:
`axis.ticks.margin` is deprecated. Please set `margin` property  of `axis.text` instead.

Comment: @BhishanPoudel Should be fixed.

Comment: @SandyMuspratt Awesome, your code works well for a single plot. Is there any way to make it work with facets as well?

Comment: @thiagovelso Sorry for the delay. Good to see you've got an answer.

Answer (score 17):

From [ggplot2 2.2.0](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/11/14/ggplot2-2-2-0/) you may use the `sec.axis` argument in `scale_`.

> `dup_axis` is a shorthand for creating a secondary axis that is a duplication of the primary axis, effectively mirroring the primary axis.

```
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work when you have discrete variables on the x axis. The argument `sec.axis` is not available in `scale_x_discrete`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the discrete issue, but the secondary axis need not be a duplication of the primary axis. So on "side=4" I can put a transformation of the "side=2" axis.

See more here:
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html

e.g., scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . + 10))