# How to add axis ticks in ggplot for multipanel plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot2 theme that I like for facetted plots, but want to add axis tickmarks as described in these threads, but this time for the multipanel case:

- [Add axis tick-marks on top and to the right to a ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949001/mirroring-axis-ticks-in-ggplot2)
- [How do I add ticks to the top and right side of a graph in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848169/how-do-i-add-ticks-to-the-top-and-right-side-of-a-graph-in-ggplot2)

As an example, I include the following code:

```
## load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

## ggplot settings
theme_update(strip.text=element_text(size=14),
             strip.text.x=element_text(vjust=1),
             strip.text.y=element_text(vjust=0,angle=90),
             strip.background=element_rect(color=NA,fill=NA,
               linetype=0),
             axis.text=element_text(size=12),
             axis.text.y=element_text(angle=90),             
             axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.3, "lines"),
             axis.ticks.margin = unit(0.5, "lines"),
             panel.border=element_rect(color=1,fill=NA),             
             panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
             panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

## transform the iris dataset
iris.long <- melt(add_rownames(iris,"Sample"),id.vars=c("Sample","Species"))
iris.long$Component <- sub("(.+)\\.(.+)","\\1",iris.long$variable)
iris.long$Dimension <- sub("(.+)\\.(.+)","\\2",iris.long$variable)
iris.wide <- dcast(iris.long,Sample+Species+Component~Dimension)

## make the plot
ggplot(iris.wide)+
  geom_point(aes(Length,Width))+
    facet_grid(Species~Component)
```

which gives the following figure:

[image: multipanel figure generated with ggplot2]

Ticks on the top and right (and also bottom and left for panels that don't have the tick labels) would be an improvement. I am not as familiar with the inner workings with the internals of ggplot/grid graphics - but is this something that can be implemented in a formulaic way? `ggplot2::annotation_logticks()` seems to have implemented such a feature, but I cannot use it with linear scale plots.

Comment: It ain't pretty, but this might serve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297155/add-floating-axis-labels-in-facet-wrap-plot/13316126#13316126

Comment: @jeremycg, thanks. fixed now.

Comment: @ShawnMehan, thanks for the suggestion but I think that's too far away from my application to adapt with minor modifications (that I can see).

Comment: There was some work done on something like this (see the files guide-axis.r and coord-.r in the package source) but it has never been "hooked up", probably because it turned out to be trickier than it seemed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use `facet_wrap`, specifying `scales = "free"` so scales vary across rows and columns and all axes are shown:

```
ggplot(iris.wide)+
  geom_point(aes(Length,Width))+
  facet_wrap(Species~Component, scales ="free", ncol = 2)
```

[image]