# flip axes of ggplot to the top and right sides using theme()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, coordinates, axis-labels

I need to flip the numbers (and tick marks) of the y-axis and x-axis to the right and top respectively (instead of where they are now). And I would like them INSIDE the map, not on the outside. This will eventually be a small inset map (without a key or any white margin space) on another larger map.

My map now:
[image]

My code:

```r
baseInset = get_map(location=c(-160.8,18.5,-154.625,22.5), zoom=8, maptype="terrain")

mapInset<-ggmap(baseInset)

Inset <- mapInset  +
            geom_point(data=CoordInset, aes(x=-Long, y=Lat, fill=Type, shape=Type),
                                            color="black", cex=1.4) + 
            scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue"), 
                              labels=c("Molokaiense (not geo-referenced)",
                                       "Oahuense (not geo-referenced)")) +
            scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,23), 
                               labels=c("Molokaiense (not geo-referenced)",
                                        "Oahuense (not geo-referenced)"))   +
            theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA, colour = "black", size=1),
                 plot.margin = unit(c(0.3, 0.3, -1.7, -0.2), 'lines'), 
                 axis.line = element_blank(), 
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=0.9, vjust=2.2, size=8), 
                 axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.15,"cm"), 
                 axis.text.y = element_text(size=8, margin = margin(r = -18)))
```

Example of the data in `CoordInset`:

```
Long      Lat                           Type

1  155.2000 19.50000             Not geo-referenced
2  155.2000 19.51600             Not geo-referenced
3  155.3433 19.67571             Not geo-referenced
4  155.4000 19.80000             Not geo-referenced
5  155.4483 19.76015             Not geo-referenced
6  155.5000 19.90000             Not geo-referenced
7  155.5000 19.80000             Not geo-referenced
8  155.6000 20.00000             Not geo-referenced
9  155.6000 19.80000             Not geo-referenced
```

I have tried to add `scale_y_continuous(position = "right")` and `scale_x_continuous(position = "top")` but I get the error message:

> ```
> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.               
> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
> ```

Is there a way to accomplish this using theme()?

The bad result:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949001/add-axis-tick-marks-on-top-and-to-the-right-to-a-ggplot